# Qtip2 Modal, firing event when closing modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, qtip2

I'm trying to trigger something with jquery when the user clicks the "x" to close the qtip2 modal.

Here's my JS for my Modal:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('.show_likes_modal').live('mouseover', function(event) {//SHOW LIKES MODAL
    clearInterval(auto_refresh); auto_refresh = 0;
    var itemid = $(this).attr("itemid");
    var itemtype = $(this).attr("itemtype");
        $(this).qtip({
        id: 'likesmodal',
        content: {
            text: '<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />',
            ajax: {url: 'modals/show_likes.php',type: 'GET',data: { itemid: itemid,itemtype:itemtype}},
            title: { text: 'People who like this:',button: true}
        },
        position: {my: 'centered',at: 'centered',target: $(window)},
        show: {event: 'click',solo: true,modal: true},
        hide: false,
        style: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded',
        events: {
        hide: function(event, api){
         auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){$('#bottom_middle').load(thisurl + '&timer=' + new Date().getTime() + ' #bottom_middle' );}, 5000);             
         $(this).qtip("destroy"); 
        }
       }        
      }); 
return false;     
}); 
</script>
```

If you notice the "hide: function(event,api) {" line, this work fine when the user click outside of the modal to close it, but when the user clicks on the "x" to close the modal, it just closes the modal.  How can I "do something" when the user clicks on the "x"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to catch the closing event of the button, I've found out that you need to catch the `mousedown` event on `.qtip-close` rather than `click`, it won't be triggered. I assume because the plugin does something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the click event of the close button yet?

```
// > jQuery 1.7
$("a.ui-tooltip-close").on("click", function() { ... });

// < jQuery 1.7
$("a.ui-tooltip-close").click(function() { ... });
```